# Freeze when open action Blueprism

Tags: rpa, blueprism

I am currently working with Blueprism 7.0.1

Every time i am trying to create a process using action Blueprism freez for several seconds
I've trying the followin solution

[image]

1. Restart my computer
2. Restart Blueprism Database
3. Repare Blueprism
4. Reinstall Blueprism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see an answer about this question in this post :

https://community.blueprism.com/discussion/freeze-when-open-action-blueprism?reply-inline=586a7b6f-0b6f-45b1-80a7-01db310fbe00

The main issue is a security issue this is caused by that my user account is differente from my administration account this create an issue in Blueprism

The solution that i am using actualy is to Shift + Right Click to open the application with another user and use administration account